# Laravel Eleqent How to use DATE_FORMAT in Postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I am writing a query to get records grouped by created_at, below is the query I have.

```
$q = Post::where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"))
                ->take(10)
                ->get(array(
                    DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
                    DB::raw('COUNT(id) as "views"')
                ))->reverse()
```

This runs without any error on mysql , but when I push the code on heroku using postgresql , I get error as :

```
ERROR:  function date_format(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist
```

Comment: Should the same code work on both MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but if someone still looking for the answer here is how you can get date in Postgresql, you can use `field_name::date` , example `created_at::date`

The above query can be written as

```
DB::select("select created_at::date, COUNT(id) as views from post where user_id = ".auth()->user()->id." group by created_at::date order by created_at desc Limit 10");
```